# Apps Script: Get user input from HTML form and save them as global variables

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The server side script below receives user input from an HTML form and adds these user data/input to the last available row of my Google Sheet. It´s been working pretty fine. But now I want to store some elements of the array that is in this script as global variables, so that I can re-use them later on in other server side functions bound to the same Google Sheet. I am specifically interested in the values inside `lastName`, `email` and `phone`. Any idea how this can be done?

Thank you so much in advance for your hints and help.

```
function AddUserInputToSheet(gender, firstName, lastName, age, email, phone) {
  var url = 'SHEET_URL';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");

  webAppSheet.appendRow([gender, firstName, lastName, age, email, phone]);
}
```

Comment: PropertiesService, store them in a spreadsheet, store them in a file

Comment: @Cooper - Been already trying to understand and use PropertiesService and ended up posting my question here, as I am not making any progress :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) of Apps Script.

> This service allows scripts to store strings as key-value pairs scoped
> to one script, one user of a script, or one document in which an
> editor add-on is used.

In your case, there are 2 options you can choose. **Script Properties** and **User Properties**.

The difference between the two is the content of **Script Properties** are shared to all users while **User Properties** is only available to the current user of a script, add-on, or web app.

Here I created an example of how to use Properties.

```
function setProperties(lastName = "Test Last Name", email = "Test Email", phone = "Test Phone"){
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperties({'lastName': lastName, 'email': email, 'phone':phone})  
}

function readProperties(){
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  Logger.log(scriptProperties.getProperties());
}
```

Here I run the `readProperties()` function first and the result is

[image]

Then I run the 'setProperties()' and rerun the `readProperties()` function again:

[image]

I reload the script page and ran the `readProperties()` function:

[image]

To add it in your script, you can set the properties in `AddUserInputToSheet()` and call it anywhere in your script.

Example:

```
function AddUserInputToSheet(gender, firstName, lastName, age, email, phone) {
  var url = 'SHEET_URL';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  webAppSheet.appendRow([gender, firstName, lastName, age, email, phone]);
  
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperties({'lastName': lastName, 'email': email, 'phone':phone})
}

function someFunction(){
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var data = scriptProperties.getProperties();
  var lastName = data["lastName"];
  var email = data["email"];
  var phone = data["phone"];
  //some operations here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
function myfunk1() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('Global1',JSON.stringify(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet0').getDataRange().getDisplayValues()));
}

function myfunk2() {
  const vs = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('Global1'))
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```